# DateTime Parsing Date with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I Want to convert this date " Apr 11 16:21:29.219 2019 GMT" to timestamp in PHP ,

This is my code :

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M d H:i:s.u Y' , 
date_format(new \DateTime("Apr 11 16:21:29.219 2019 GMT)") ));               
$response_time = strtotime($matches[1]);
```

But the result is null , 
Any ideas please ? 
Thank You !

Comment: `strtotime("Apr 11 16:21:29.219 2019 GMT")`

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa that doesn't work either...

Comment: `echo strtotime("Apr 11 2019  16:21:29.219 GMT");`

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of issues, you shouldn't be attempting to make a `DateTime` object directly from the string (that's what `\DateTime::createFromFormat` is for) and you are missing the required `e` format character to match the `GMT` part of the string. Try this:

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M d H:i:s.u Y e', "Apr 11 16:21:29.219 2019 GMT");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
```

Output:

```
2019-04-11 16:21:29.219000
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/56TDE)